# Cronitor CLI usage is different from documentation

Tags: python, linux, raspbian

I'm trying to install the Cronitor CLI on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. I've followed the steps from [here](https://cronitor.io/docs/using-cronitor-cli), swapping amd64 for arm and taking /local/ out of the third command to match to where I put it with the second command. The specific commands I used were:

```
curl -sOL https://cronitor.io/dl/linux_arm.tar.gz
sudo tar xvf linux_arm.tar.gz -C /usr/bin/
sudo /usr/bin/cronitor configure --api-key [my api key]
```

When I run "cronitor discover" after installing I get the following usage message:

```
usage: cronitor [-h] [--apiKey APIKEY] [--id ID] [--code CODE] [--msg MSG]
                (--run | --complete | --fail | --ok | --pause PAUSE)
```

I haven't been able to find anywhere online where this usage is specified, and I'm not sure why this is different from what the documentation says. I do have the Cronitor python3 package installed using "sudo pip3 install cronitor", but my understanding is that it should not interfere, right? Any help would be appreciated.

To resolve the issue I have uninstalled both the CLI and the Python package and tried to reinstall the CLI without the Python package installed. It gives me the same results.

EDIT: For anyone stumbling across this same error in the future, "sudo cronitor" works as intended! Use sudo to access the CLI!

Comment: When you're inputting your api key, are you just entering it as is or are you putting quotes around it. It shouldn't really matter in the CLI but the docs do specify a string and maybe they want that string in quotes. Maybe.

A few more questions: 
- What is the output of `cronitor status`?
- Are there any differences between `sudo cronitor ...` and `cronitor ...`?
- Have you tried setting the api key as an environmental variable, like `export CRONITOR_API_KEY=<your api key>`?

These are just ideas

Comment: @Huessy I initially entered the api key with no quotes, but I just tried it again with quotes and got the same result. "cronitor status" returns the same usage message. "sudo cronitor" actually worked, I got the CLI to work as intended. Thanks for your help with it!

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Ubuntu22.04. I tried with sudo but same result!